# copy MySql DB from one server to another

Tags: mysql

I need to copy a MySQL DB from a server on Linux to a server on Windows. I've tried using mysqldump but it doesn't seem to include Stored Procs. I want to copy everything, i.e. schema, data, stored procs, triggers, etc.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the "[--routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines)" option of [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

From the documentation for --routines flag:

> Dump stored routines (procedures and
>   functions) from the dumped databases.
>   Use of this option requires the SELECT
>   privilege for the mysql.proc table.
>   The output generated by using
>   --routines contains CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION statements to
>   re-create the routines. However, these
>   statements do not include attributes
>   such as the routine creation and
>   modification timestamps. This means
>   that when the routines are reloaded,
>   they will be created with the
>   timestamps equal to the reload time.
>
> If you require routines to be
>   re-created with their original
>   timestamp attributes, do not use
>   --routines. Instead, dump and reload the contents of the mysql.proc table
>   directly, using a MySQL account that
>   has appropriate privileges for the
>   mysql database.
>
> This option was added in MySQL 5.1.2.
>   Before that, stored routines are not
>   dumped. Routine DEFINER values are not
>   dumped until MySQL 5.1.8. This means
>   that before 5.1.8, when routines are
>   reloaded, they will be created with
>   the definer set to the reloading user.
>   If you require routines to be
>   re-created with their original
>   definer, dump and load the contents of
>   the mysql.proc table directly as
>   described earlier.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqldump -u root -p --routines --databases io \
| sed -e "s/;;/\$\$/g" \
> io.sql
```

please try dump. and import command to :

```
mysql -u root -p --fource --databases io < io.sql
```